# update array value in mongod with insert

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to do the followings :-

1. find userId if exist else create one
2. find userId and push the item into the array, and if the item already existed don't push

**Schema**

```
var ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "userId" : {
         type:String
    },
    "item" : []
});
```

I can do, `findOne` then get the array, then find the array exist or not, else push and then save it.

Just curious is there any built in `mongoose` to do so?

Comment: What is the type of the elements in the `item` array?

Comment: You can try `$set` to do  `update` with `upsert as true` to achieve the first one. You can try `$addtoset` to achieve the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution To your Problem:

```
ItemSchema.findOne({"userId":"yourId"},function(err,data){
   if(data.length > 0){
    console.log("USER EXISTS");
    var newItemPush="newItem";
    //For Task 2
    //Add Item if Item Does not Exits 
    ItemSchema.find({"userId":"yourId"},{ item: { $elemMatch: { item: newItemPush } } },function(err,data){
         if(data.length > 0){
            console.log("ADDING NEW ITEM");
            ItemSchema.findOneAndUpdate({"userId":"yourId"},{ item: { $elemMatch: { item: newItemPush } } },function(err,data){
                if(data){
                   console.log("NEW ITEM PUSHED SUCCESSFULLY");
                }

            });
         }
    }); 
   }
   else {
    //Task 1
    console.log("USER DOES NOT EXISTS NOW CREATE ONE");
    var insertData={
        userId:"newUserId",
        {$push: { item: "your item" } }

    }
    ItemSchema.update({},insertData,function(err,data){
        if(data){
            console.log("DATA INSERTED")
        }
        else{
            console.log("DATA NOT INSERTED:"+err);
        }
    }) 
   }

});
```

Comment: it used double find, can't it be better? why don't use one find, get all the array and use native javascript function to make the array unique, then push it?

Comment: Even if you do that it ll take 2 queries so its one and the same,One to get all the arrays and other to push that unique arrays!!!!!